# static and non-static variable definition at the start of the file difference

Tags: c

Looking at an ST example file for one of its devices.

On the same .c file there are different definitions.

Curious to know what might be the reason for some of the definitions to be static and some not.

```
PLACE_IN_SECTION("BLE_DRIVER_CONTEXT") static tListNode HciAsynchEventQueue; // static

PLACE_IN_SECTION("BLE_DRIVER_CONTEXT") static TL_CmdPacket_t *pCmdBuffer; // static

PLACE_IN_SECTION("BLE_DRIVER_CONTEXT") HCI_TL_UserEventFlowStatus_t UserEventFlow; // not static
```

All appear at the top of the file . One after another. All are used inside the file only.

Comment: A `static` variable cannot be accessed from another file with `extern`.

Comment: You omit `static` when you want to do spaghetti programming with globals. That's about the only reason why. So either they want the user to access this variable as part of a spaghetti API design, or it's a bug.

Comment: I took a glance at this lib at some Github and it would appear that the missing `static` is simply a sloppy bug. They don't seem to intend other files to use it. This could have been prevented by implementing professional development routines, such as running code intended for embedded systems though a MISRA-C checker. As required by most customers STM32 is targeting...

Answer (score 1):

`static` file level (global) variables do not have external linkage and will not be seen from other compilation units (more simple files). They have the same storage duration as non `static` variables but their "visibility" is limited to one compilation unit (source file).